# Error in registration token from GCM iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging

Registration token is nil always and show this error : The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.iid error 0.)

**AppDelegate.m**

```
GGLInstanceIDConfig *instanceIDConfig = [GGLInstanceIDConfig defaultConfig];
instanceIDConfig.delegate = self;
[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] startWithConfig:instanceIDConfig];

registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                         kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@YES};
[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:@"mySenderID"
                                                          scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                  options:registrationOptions
                                                  handler:registrationHandler];

 registrationHandler = ^(NSString *registrationToken, NSError *error){

    if (registrationToken != nil) {

        myRegistrationToken = registrationToken;

        NSLog(@"Registration Token: %@", registrationToken);

        NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"registrationToken":registrationToken};

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Registration to GCM failed with error: %@",    error.localizedDescription);
    }
};
```

Comment: Take look at the official document here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start?ver=swift and go through those steps, you will get the `registrationToken` successfully.